# Wiener Algebra, absolute convergence of fourier series

Tags: fourier-series, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

So how do you prove if $f, g\in L^2(\mathbb{T})$, then $f*g\in \mathbb{A}(\mathbb{T})$. $\mathbb{T}$ denote $[0,1)$ and $\mathbb{A}(\mathbb{T})$ denote the Wiener algebra such that if $f\in \mathbb{A}(\mathbb{T})$, then $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |\widehat{f}(n)|<\infty$$ We define 
$$||f||_{\mathbb{A}}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}|\hat{f}(n)|$$

I know that $\widehat{f*g}=\widehat{f}\widehat{g}$, but how can this help

Comment: And $\widehat{f},\widehat{g}\in\ell^2$, so this does follow from the formula for the convolution.

Comment: you get $\widehat{f}$ and $\widehat{g}\in l^2$ from the fact that they are in $L^2$?

Comment: @amathnerd : $\|f\|^{2}_{L^{2}}=\sum_{n}|\hat{f}(n)|^{2}$ is Parseval's equality, and if $f \in L^{1}$, then $f\in L^{2}\iff \hat{f}\in l^{2}$.